# T-SQL Calling Scalar Function in Where Speed

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have the following query:

```
SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE [dbo].GetNumOnOrder([Id]) = 0
```

With the following "GetNumOnOrder" Scalar-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumOnOrder]
(
    @ProductId INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumOnOrder INT

    SELECT @NumOnOrder = SUM([NumOrdered] - [NumReceived])
    FROM [dbo].[PurchaseOrderDetails]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PurchaseOrders]
        ON [PurchaseOrderDetails].[PurchaseOrderId] = [PurchaseOrders].[Id]
    WHERE [PurchaseOrders].[StatusId] <> 5
        AND [PurchaseOrderDetails].[ProductId] = @ProductId

    RETURN CASE WHEN @NumOnOrder IS NOT NULL THEN @NumOnOrder ELSE 0 END
END
```

However it takes around 6 seconds to execute. Unfortunately I have no control over the initial SQL generated but I can change the function. Is there any way the function can be modified to speed this up? I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Couldn't you just join the tables used in the function to the products table, and do the calculation directly?

Comment: I wish I could but unfortunately I have no control on the outer SQL but I can change the function as much as I like. I've updated my question to specify this.

Comment: Yeah this query is just going to be exponentially slower as you get more data in the products table since the function is called for every single row in the table. If you have no control over the outer sql then I don't think there is much you can do.

Comment: @P_G - Well linearly slower as more data is added to the products table. Possibly exponentially slower if more data is added to the `PurchaseOrder*` tables concurrently. Agree that there is not much that can be done to improve performance given those constraints though.

Comment: All you can do under those constraints is to make sure that the query used by the function is as efficient as possible. Best to get the constraints changed.

Comment: Most important thing is to check that you have an index on `[PurchaseOrderDetails].[ProductId]` (and even force use of this index with query hint http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/08/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint-part2/ ). Also, change the `WHERE` to `AND` (but the optimizer should already treat it as an `AND` )

Comment: do you have any control the indexes on the tables in the query?  what flavour of SQL Server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the rights to add indexes to the tables (and dependant on the version of SQL Server you are using), I would investigate what performance gain adding the following would have:-

```
create index newindex1 on PurchaseOrders (id) 
    include (StatusId);
create index newindex2 on PurchaseOrderDetails (PurchaseOrderId) 
    include (ProductId,NumOrdered,NumReceived);
```

You probably already have indexes on these columns - but the indexes above will support just the query in your function in the most efficient way possible (reducing the number of page reads to a minimum).  If the performance of this function is important enough, you could also consider adding a calculated column into your table - for `NumOrdered-NumReceived` (and then only include the result column in the index above - and your query).  You could also consider doing this in an indexed view rather than the table - but schema binding a view can by tiresome and inconvenient.  Obviously, the wider the tables in question are - the greater the improvement in performance will be.

Comment: Thanks this made a big enough improvement to make it bearable. However it looks like this query will get slower as more data is added so I'll look to refactor using CRAFTY DBA's solution in the future.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use a function and can not live without it, use a in-line table value version.  It is a-lot faster.  Check out these articles from some experts.

http://aboutsqlserver.com/2011/10/23/sunday-t-sql-tip-inline-vs-multi-statement-table-valued-functions/

http://dataeducation.com/scalar-functions-inlining-and-performance-an-entertaining-title-for-a-boring-post/

I have had a couple MVP friends say that this the only function they ever write since scalar functions are treated as a bunch of Stored Procedure calls.

Re-write using in-line table value function. Check the syntax since I did not.  Use the Coalesce function to convert NULL to Zero.

```
--
-- Table value function
--

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumOnOrder] ( @ProductId INT )
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    SELECT 
        COALESCE(SUM([NumOrdered] - [NumReceived]), 0) AS Num 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[PurchaseOrderDetails]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PurchaseOrders]
        ON [PurchaseOrderDetails].[PurchaseOrderId] = [PurchaseOrders].[Id]
    WHERE [PurchaseOrders].[StatusId] <> 5
        AND [PurchaseOrderDetails].[ProductId] = @ProductId
);

--
-- Sample call with cross apply
--

SELECT [Id] 
FROM [dbo].[Products] P
CROSS APPLY [dbo].[GetNumOnOrder] (C.Id) AS CI
WHERE CI.Num = 0;
```

Comment: This would still require a change to the calling code though. The query `SELECT [Id] FROM [dbo].[Products] WHERE [dbo].GetNumOnOrder([Id]) = 0` was apparently handed down in tablets of stone as far as the problem statement is concerned.

Comment: Good luck then.  Regular functions are slow ... That is a known fact!  I would try to work with the designer/vendor to change the code.

Answer (score 0):

If the data is unevenly distributed data in table `PurchaseOrderDetails` then cached query plans might impact your query performance. This is a case where "`Parameter Sniffing`" might create bad query plans. Actually SQL Server supports an optimization called "parameter sniffing", where it will choose different plan based on the particular values in `@ProductId` variable.
So to improve performance of your query you can re-write your function as:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNumOnOrder]
(
    @ProductId INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumOnOrder INT,@v_ProductId INT
    SET @v_ProductId = @ProductId;

    SELECT @NumOnOrder = SUM([NumOrdered] - [NumReceived])
    FROM [dbo].[PurchaseOrderDetails]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PurchaseOrders]
        ON [PurchaseOrderDetails].[PurchaseOrderId] = [PurchaseOrders].[Id]
    WHERE [PurchaseOrders].[StatusId] <> 5
        AND [PurchaseOrderDetails].[ProductId] = @v_ProductId

    RETURN CASE WHEN @NumOnOrder IS NOT NULL THEN @NumOnOrder ELSE 0 END
END
```

or you can include a Recomplie hint.